# pymongo basic functions not working

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Here's a really basic mongodb client.

```
import pymongo

MONGO_DBNAME = 'db'
MONGO_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
MONGO_PORT = '5001'
MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://'+MONGO_HOST+':'+MONGO_PORT+'/'+MONGO_DBNAME

mongo = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGO_URI)
data = mongo.db['data']
data.insert_one({'data':'0.0'})
```

I get the error: 
`ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 0.0.0.0:5001: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context`

It's only that last command that screws things up. I've tried insert_many() with an array and get the same error, but I don't see what is wrong. Halp?

Edit: yes I've tried that other solution but I don't think it's the same.
Here's a flask example with a similar error

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
#import urllib
#from pprint import pprint

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'robo'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/robo'

mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route('/ya')
def ya():
    data = mongo.db.data
    data.insert_one({'test':'case'})
    return str(data)

@app.route('/uhhuh')
def uhhuh():
    data = mongo.db.data
    cursor = data.find({})
    x = []

    for doc in cursor:
        x.append(str(doc))

    return str(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

--

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
    127.0.0.1 - - [17/May/2018 17:46:01] "GET /ya HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Default port for MongoDB is `27017` and it does not bind to `0.0.0.0` by default. Unless you actually have already changed the `mongod` server configuration, then you actually want `localhost` and the default port. `localhost` and `0.0.0.0` are not the same thing.

Comment: Check my edit? I still get an error

Comment: Are you running `mongod`? Probably not. That's the other detail in the linked question you seem to be ignoring.

Comment: The one you linked didn't mention anything about mongod, actually yours is the first mention of it I've seen. So mongodb doesn't work on localhost by default without mongod.exe?

Comment: You need to run a server. The `pymongo` library is just a means of communicating with the "server". See [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Windows](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) in the official documentation.

Comment: Yup just read through all that and got it going. I had assumed pymongo created an instance for me. Thank you.